# An Array of Objects Within An Array of Objects in Java

Tags: java, arrays, object

Im doing a school assignment and im really struggling with part of this question. Our Code essentially requires us to have multiple Portfolio arrays with Multiple policies store inside each portfolio. Would I need to create an array of objects to do this? Bearing in mind that both Portfolio and Policy are objects. Any help would be appreciated as Im very confused on this one. Thanks in advance!

```
import java.text.DateFormat;//import Statements
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;

public class Menu
{
    public static void main(String[]args)//main class
    {
        String StringDate = null;
        //Code Implemented to convert user String input to Calendar Format
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("DD/MM/YYYY");
        Calendar newDOB = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar newsDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar neweDate = Calendar.getInstance();


        //int to allow user input to navigate menu system

        int IntInput = 0;//menu class specific variables declared
        String newName;
        String newID;
        String newPolicyNum;
        String newPolicyType;
        String newStatus;
        String newPolicyName;

        //arrays declared
        Portfolio[] Portfolio = new Portfolio[1];
        MotorPolicy[] MotorPolicy = new MotorPolicy[1];
        HomePolicy[] HomePolicy = new HomePolicy[1];
        MobilePhonePolicy[] MobilePolicy = new MobilePhonePolicy[1];
        Policy[] Policy = new Policy[1];

        Scanner num = new Scanner(System.in);//scanners created
        Scanner let = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        int menuChoice;

        do //do loop to run main menu
        {
            System.out.println("   --------------------Welcome to Insurance World------------------- ");
            System.out.println("   ----------Insurance That's Truely 'Out Of This World'------------ ");
            System.out.println("  |_________________________________________________________________|");
            System.out.println("1)| Create An Insurance Portfolio                                   |");
            System.out.println("  |-----------------------------------------------------------------|");
            System.out.println("2)| Amend Portfolio Details                                         |");
            System.out.println("  |-----------------------------------------------------------------|");
            System.out.println("3)| Display a Portfolio                                             |");
            System.out.println("  |-----------------------------------------------------------------|");
            System.out.println("4)| Create An Insurance Policy                                      |");
            System.out.println("  |-----------------------------------------------------------------|");
            System.out.println("5)| Amend Policy Details                                            |");
            System.out.println("  |-----------------------------------------------------------------|");
            System.out.println("6)| Cancel A Policy                                                 |");
            System.out.println("  |-----------------------------------------------------------------|");
            System.out.println("7)| Display a Policy                                                |");
            System.out.println("  |-----------------------------------------------------------------|");
            System.out.println("8)| Exit Program                                                    |");
            System.out.println("  |_________________________________________________________________|");

            menuChoice = keyboard.nextInt();//menu input

            if (menuChoice == 1)//create a portfolio
            {
                for(int i = 1; i<Portfolio.length; i++)//counter is declared 
                {
                    Portfolio[i] = new Portfolio();//Portfolio initialised  
                    System.out.println("Please Enter The Name of The Portfolio Holder: ");
                    newName=let.nextLine();

                    System.out.println("Please Enter Your DoB(DD/MM/YYYY): ");
                    StringDate=let.nextLine();

                    System.out.println("Your ID Number is: " + i);
                    newID = " " + i;

                    Portfolio[i].setId(" " + i);
                    Portfolio[i].setName(newName);//assigning values to portfolio methods
                    Portfolio[i].setDOB(newDOB);
                    Portfolio[i].setNumPolicies(0);
                    Portfolio[i].getDateCreated();

                    System.out.println("Your Portfolio Will Look Like This: ");

                    i++;//Counter incremented
                }
            }
            else if(menuChoice == 2)
            {
                //amend portfolio details

                System.out.println("Please Enter The ID Number Of The Portfolio You Wish To Amend: ");
                IntInput=num.nextInt();
                Portfolio[IntInput].toString();

                int amendChoice;
                System.out.println("What do you want to Change? ");
                System.out.println("1) Name of Portfolio Holder ");
                System.out.println("2) Date Of Birth of Portfolio Holder ");
                System.out.println("3) ID of Portfolio ");
                System.out.println("4) Exit Program ");
                amendChoice=num.nextInt();//user input

                if(amendChoice == 1)
                {
                    System.out.println("Please Enter the Updated Name of the Portfolio Holder: ");
                    newName=let.nextLine();
                    Portfolio[IntInput].setName(newName);
                    System.out.println("Your New Portfolio Will Look Like This: ");
                    Portfolio[IntInput].toString();
                }
                else if(amendChoice == 2)
                {
                    System.out.println("Please Enter the Updated DOB of the Portfolio Holder: ");
                    //newDOB=keyboard.nextLine();
                    Portfolio[IntInput].setDOB(newDOB);
                    System.out.println("Your New Portfolio will Look Like This: ");
                    Portfolio[IntInput].toString();
                }
                else if(amendChoice == 3)
                {
                    System.out.println("Please Enter the Updated ID of the Portfolio: ");
                    newID=let.nextLine();
                    Portfolio[IntInput].setId(newID);
                    System.out.println("Your New Portfolio Will Look Like This: ");
                    Portfolio[IntInput].toString();
                }
                else if(amendChoice == 4)
                {
                    System.out.println("Exiting Menu");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("The Number You Entered isn't a Valid Choice");
                }
            }
            else if(menuChoice == 3)//display portfolio details
            {

                System.out.println("Please Enter the ID of the Portfolio you wish to View: ");
                Portfolio[num.nextInt()].toString();
            }
            else if(menuChoice == 4)//create a new policy
            {
                int Counter=1;
                do
                {
                    int subMenuChoice;//Menu to Choose policy type
                    System.out.println("Please Choose The type of Policy You Want: ");
                    System.out.println("1) Motor Insurance Policy");
                    System.out.println("2) Home Insurance Policy");
                    System.out.println("3) Mobile Phone Insurance Policy");
                    System.out.println("4) Travel Insurance Policy");
                    subMenuChoice=num.nextInt();

                    if(subMenuChoice==1)
                    {
                        MotorPolicy[Counter] = new MotorPolicy();

                        MotorPolicy[Counter].setPolicyType("Motor Insurance");
                        MotorPolicy[Counter].setPolicyNum(" " + Counter);

                        System.out.println("Please Enter the Name of the Policy Holder: ");
                        newPolicyName=let.nextLine();
                        MotorPolicy[Counter].setPolicyName(newPolicyName);

                        System.out.println("Please Enter Your DoB (DD/MM/YYYY): ");
                        StringDate=let.nextLine();
                        MotorPolicy[Counter].setDob(newDOB);

                        System.out.println("Please Enter The Date You Want Your Policy To Start (DD/MM/YYYY): ");
                        StringDate=let.nextLine();
                        MotorPolicy[Counter].setSDate(newsDate);

                        System.out.println("Please Enter The Date You Want Yourt Policy To End (DD/MM/YYYY): ");
                        StringDate=let.nextLine();
                        MotorPolicy[Counter].setEDate(neweDate);

                        System.out.println("Please Enter the Registration Number of your Car: ");
                        int newRegNum = num.nextInt();
                        MotorPolicy[Counter].setCarRegistrationNumber(newRegNum);

                        System.out.println("Please Enter The Model of Your Car: ");
                        String newModel = let.nextLine();
                        MotorPolicy[Counter].setModel(newModel);

                        System.out.println("Please Enter The Value Of Your Car: ");
                        double newValue = num.nextDouble();
                        MotorPolicy[Counter].setVehicleValue(newValue);

                        System.out.println("We Will Calculate Your Motor Insurance Premium!");
                        MotorPolicy[Counter].calcMotorPremium(newsDate, neweDate, newValue);
                        System.out.println("We Calculated Your Premium to Be: £" + MotorPolicy[Counter].getPremium());
                        Counter++;
                    }
                    else if(subMenuChoice==2)
                    {
                        Policy[Counter].setPolicyType("Home Insurance");

                        Counter++;
                    }
                    else if(subMenuChoice==3)
                    {
                        Policy[Counter].setPolicyType("Mobile Phone Insurance");

                        Counter++;
                    }
                    else if(subMenuChoice==4)
                    {
                        Policy[Counter].setPolicyType("Travel Insurance");

                        Counter++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("The Number You Entered Doesn't Correspond To A Choice!");//Validation for policy choice menu
                    }
                }
                while(Counter<10);
            }
            else if(menuChoice == 5)
            {
                //amend policy details
            }
            else if(menuChoice == 6)
            {
                //cancel policy
            }
            else if(menuChoice == 7)
            {
                //display policy
                System.out.println("Please Enter The Policy Number of The Policy You Want to View: ");
                IntInput = let.nextInt();
                Policy[IntInput].toString();
                //IntInput = keyboard.nextInt();
                //Portfolio[IntInput].toString();
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("The Input you entered doesn't correspond to a choice!");//validation method 
            }
        }

        while(menuChoice != 8); //exit condition
        {
            System.out.println("Exiting Program!");
        }
    }
}
```

Portfolio Class:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;//import statements


public class Portfolio 
{
    private String id;//variables declared
    private String name;
    private Calendar dob;
    private Calendar dateCreated;
    private int numPolicies;




    public Portfolio(String id, String name, Calendar dob)//portfolio constructor
    {
        this.id=id;
        this.name=name;
        this.dob=dob;
        dateCreated = Calendar.getInstance();
        numPolicies=0;
    }

    public Portfolio()
    {
        id = " ";//variables given null values
        name = " ";
        dob = null;
        dateCreated = null;
        numPolicies = 0;
    }


    public void setId(String id)//set methods
    {
        this.id=id;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name=name;
    }

    public void setDOB(Calendar dob)
    {
        this.dob=dob;
    }

    public void setDateCreated(Calendar dateCreated)
    {
        this.dateCreated=dateCreated;
    }

    public void setNumPolicies(int numPolicies)
    {
        this.numPolicies=numPolicies;
    }

    public String getId()//get methods
    {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public Calendar getDob()
    {
        return dob;
    }

    public Calendar getDateCreated()
    {
        return dateCreated;
    }

    public void acceptPolicy(Policy p)//accept a policy 'p' and link it to the portfolio
    {
        p.setPortfolio(this);
        p.setStatus("ACTIVE");
        numPolicies = numPolicies +1;//adds one policy to the portfolio
    }

    public String toString()//method to output portfolio data
    {
        String str = " ";
        str = str + "ID: " + id + "\n";
        str = str + "Name: " + name + "\n";

        if(dob!=null)
        {
            str = str + "DOB: " + dob.get(Calendar.DATE) + "/" + (dob.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + dob.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "\n";
        }
        if(dateCreated!=null)
        {
            str = str + "Date Created: " + dateCreated.get(Calendar.DATE) + "/" + (dateCreated.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + dateCreated.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "\n"; 
        }

        str = str + "Number of Policies: " + numPolicies + "\n";
        return str;
    }



}
```

Policy Class:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
class Policy
{

    private String policyNum, Pname, policyType, status;
    private Calendar dob, sDate, eDate;
    private double dailyRate, premium;
    private Portfolio portfolio;

    public Policy(String policyNum, String Pname, Calendar dob, Calendar sDate, Calendar eDate, String policyType, double dailyRate )
    {
        this.policyNum = policyNum;
        this.Pname = Pname;
        this.dob = dob;
        this.sDate = sDate;
        this.eDate = eDate;
        this.policyType = policyType;
        status = " ";
        this.dailyRate = dailyRate;
        premium = 0;
        portfolio = null;
    }

    public Policy()
    {
        policyNum = " ";
        Pname = " ";
        dob = null;
        sDate = null;
        eDate = null;
        policyType = " ";
        status = " ";
        dailyRate = 0;
        premium = 0;
        portfolio = null;
    }

    //set methods
    public void setPolicyNum (String policyNum)
    {
        this.policyNum = policyNum;
    }

    public void setPolicyName (String Pname)
    {
        this.Pname = Pname;
    }

    public void setDob (Calendar dob)
    {
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    public void setSDate (Calendar sDate)
    {
        this.sDate = sDate;
    }

    public void setEDate (Calendar eDate)
    {
        this.eDate = eDate;
    }

    public void setPolicyType (String policyType)
    {
        this.policyType = policyType;
    }

    public void setStatus (String status)
    {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public void setDailyRate (double dailyRate)
    {
        this.dailyRate = dailyRate;
    }

    public void setPremium (double premium)
    {
        this.premium = premium;
    }

     public void setPortfolio (Portfolio portfolio)
     {
        this.portfolio = portfolio;
    }

    //get methods
    public String getPolicyNum()
    {
        return policyNum;
    }

    public String getPolicyName()
    {
        return Pname;
    }

    public Calendar getDob()
    {
        return dob;
    }

    public Calendar getSDate()
    {
        return sDate;
    }

    public Calendar getEDate()
    {
        return eDate;
    }

    public String getPolicyType()
    {
        return policyType;
    }

    public String getStatus()
    {
        return status;
    }

    public double getDailyRate()
    {
        return dailyRate;
    }

    public double getPremium()
    {
        return premium;
    }

    public Portfolio getPortfolio()
    {
        return portfolio;
    }

    public void cancelPolicy(Calendar eDate)
    {
        this.eDate = eDate;
        status = "CANCELLED";
    }

    public double calcPremium()
    {
        //work out number of days of policy and calculate premium based on a daily rate
        if(sDate!= null && eDate!= null)
        {
            long time1 = sDate.getTimeInMillis();
            long time2 = eDate.getTimeInMillis();
            long diff = time2 - time1;
            long days = diff/1000/60/60/24;

            return (days * dailyRate);
        }
        else
            return 0;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        String str = " ";
        str = str + "Policy Number: " + policyNum + "\n";
        str = str + "Name: " + Pname + "\n";

        if (dob!= null)
        {
            str = str + "DOB: "+ dob.get(Calendar.DATE) +  "/" + (dob.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + dob.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "\n";
        }
        if (sDate!= null)
        {
            str = str + "Start Date: "+ sDate.get(Calendar.DATE) +  "/" + (sDate.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + sDate.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "\n";
        }
        if (eDate!= null)
        {
            str = str + "Start Date: "+ eDate.get(Calendar.DATE) +  "/" + (eDate.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + eDate.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "\n";
        }
        str = str + "Policy Type: " + policyType + "\n";
        str = str + "Policy Status: " + status + "\n";
        str = str + "Policy Daily Rate: " + dailyRate + "\n";
        if (portfolio!= null)
        {
            str = str + "Related Portfolio Reference: " + portfolio.getId() + "\n";
        }
        str = str + "Policy Premium: " + premium + "\n";
        return str;
    }
```

Comment: Please consider these [steps](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) specifically on making your post more concise or provide examples whats happening and what you want to happen.

Comment: You're trying to do far too much in your `main()` method. You should delegate the code to other methods and classes.

Comment: How are the portfolio and policy classes connected?

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, the things still a work in progress so its a mess. Portfolio and Policy both have their own separate classes but the only really connection between them is that Policy has a variable called Portfolio in it. see code below:

Comment: Please edit your question with the code instead of putting it in the comments (It's very hard to read unformatted code)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what your question is. Yes, if you have multiple Portfolios, you need an array. If Portfolios contain Policies, then Portfolio is going to need an array inside himself. This is VERY VERY common in coding. It's not any different than Portfolio containing other fields like id and name.

Comment: Thanks for the help:) Sorry aswell if my question was dumb but i've only been coding since september as part of my degree, Have a good one:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jsheeran said you should delegate some of the responsibilities to methods. This helps you write more reusable code, and makes it easier to find the errors. And then if you later want to update your code/change the functionality, you only have to (usually) only have to modify the method instead of hunting through your code to find what you need to change. Also it's best to only have one `Scanner` object to read from the console. Now on to your question

What I would do to solve this problem is to have the Portfolio class have an arrayList property that stores `Policy` objects (As that's the whole purpose of a portfolio) An `ArrayList` can change in size so it's probably best to use.

So something like:

```
private ArrayList<Policy> policies;
//getters and setters
```

And then in your main you could simply create an `ArrayList` of portfolio objects and add the policies to each `Portfolio` object.

```
ArrayList<Portfolio> portfolios = new ArrayList<>();
//Add your porfolios
```

And then you could do everything much like you did in your original program

Comment: Thank you so much!! Just to clarify would I declare the Policies array list inside the policies class or inside my main method? And I will start removing stuff from the main method and putting in the other classes aswell:)